# cannot select button by xpath in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

```
button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[1]/main/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[3]/button")

button.click()
```

when I try to run my code I get the exception: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[1]/main/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[3]/button"}
(Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.164

meanwhile its the xpath of the button which is found https://www.zalando.fr/login

and this is the element

Se connecter

i've tried finding it by class name and everything it just doesn't work

Comment: can you let us know if the below answers helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xpath ended up being wrong. I copied it from chrometools and tried later with brave and I got the correct xpath.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this where need to handle the cookie window which is getting displayed after the page is getting loaded and used `explicitWait`

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver.get("https://www.zalando.fr/login")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space()='OK']"))).click()

#here I'm passing the user name
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='login.email']").send_keys("email")
#here passing password
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='login.password']").send_keys("password")

#clicking on the `Se connecter` button
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-testid='login_button']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your locator is wrong.
Also use explicit wait.
Try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-testid='login_button']"))).click()
```